# How do I export the data from an Oracle SQL Developer query

Tags: export, database-administration, sqldeveloper

How do I export the data from an Oracle SQL Developer query?

I can create queries in it fine, but as to export?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLDeveloper can export data to csv, xml, text
Here is the link to tutorial of SQL Developer http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/SQLDeveloper/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [SQLPAL](http://www.sqlpal.com) if you're running Windows, as it exports to an Excel worksheet.